# subset items in the list by matching part of strings

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have two lists:

```
list1 <- list("aaa.bbb.txt", "ccc.dddd.txt", "e.ff.txt", "gg.hhh.txt")
list2 <- list("ff","hhh" )
```

I want to subset `list1` to items that match with `list2`. In this case `list1` would contain only these two items `"e.ff.txt", "gg.hhh.txt"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
pat <- paste(list2,collapse="|")
list1[sapply(list1, function(x) length(grep(pat,x))) >0]
#[[1]]
#[1] "e.ff.txt"

#[[2]]
#[1] "gg.hhh.txt"
```

Or for this example, the below code also works.

```
list1[grepl(pat, list1)]
#[[1]]
#[1] "e.ff.txt"

#[[2]]
#[1] "gg.hhh.txt"
```